# Is there any way to apply loop in a presto query

Tags: sql, bigdata, presto

My use case is to use the below presto view on top of the table to get daily count by subtracting the todays value with that of yesterday. If there is no data in the table then the view should dynamically consider next day value and then take the average for the missing day view.

This is a presto query. I have taken only one field in the below query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW hive.facebook.post_metrics_daily AS
SELECT
    a.post_id,
    a.page,
    a.dt,
    a.created_time,
    (
        COALESCE(
            (
                CAST(a.likes AS integer) 
                - IF(
                    (CAST(b.likes AS integer) IS NULL), 
                    0, 
                    CAST(b.likes AS integer)
                )
            )
            , 0
        )
    ) likes
FROM
    hive.facebook.post_metrics a                 
    LEFT JOIN hive.facebook.post_metrics b 
        ON  a.dt = (b.dt + INTERVAL  '+1' DAY)
        AND a.post_id = b.post_id 
        AND a.brandname = b.brandname
WHERE a.dt = date'2019-09-10'
```

If the data is for 9th to 12th and 10th data is missing then the view should take 11th day data and take the avg of 9th and 11th to give the 10th view. How can It be done? Can this formula be applied in the query and If yes then how?

`(today-yesterday)/n+1` where `n` will be the number of days missing.

This is the sample data for likes. In case of missing likes, I need avg likes and the number of days which is missing should be dynamically identified by the query..

```
 Date   Likes-org.  missing likes daily likes org.   expected likes
2019-10-17  20487   20487         20487                  20487
2019-10-18  25384   25384          4897                  4897
2019-10-19  26817   26817          1433                  1433
2019-10-20  27499   missing likes   682                   257
2019-10-21  27854   missing likes   355                   258
2019-10-22  27987   missing likes   133                   258
2019-10-23  28065   missing likes   78                    258
2019-10-24  28106   28106           41                    258
2019-10-25  28134   28134           28                     28
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have updated the sample data @gordon

Comment: lag() works on row level I guess. I need to find diff between the row of diff dates which are in diff partition for the same id based on data for available dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
SELECT pm.*,
       (pm.likes +
        LAG(pm.likes) OVER (PARTITION BY pm.post_id, pm.brand_name ORDER BY pm.dt)
       ) / 2
FROM hive.facebook.post_metrics pm ;
```

If you want to treat the missing days as `0`s, you need date arithmetic.  I think this would be:

```
SELECT pm.*,
       ( (pm.likes +
          LAG(pm.likes) OVER (PARTITION BY pm.post_id, pm.brand_name ORDER BY pm.dt)
         ) /
         DATE_DIFF(day,
                   LAG(pm.dt) OVER (PARTITION BY pm.post_id, pm.brand_name ORDER BY pm.dt),
                   dt
                  )
       )
FROM hive.facebook.post_metrics pm ;
```

If you want this for a particular day, use a subquery or for the above expression and then filter in the outer query.

Comment: I think this would not be the actual sol I want. Suppose If I create a view for say 21st then the view should just return me likes as 258. This is what I expect.